# :hover { cursor: pointer } on circle created via borderradius will make it a pointer even outside the circle

Tags: javascript, css

I've created a circle button using border-radius. My issue is that when using the following code:
`button:hover {cursor: pointer}` the cursor will be a pointer even outside the circle ( but inside the "rectangular div"). Im pretty sure I need javascript to solve this (althou I've included the CSS tag in case im wrong), but other than that Im blank, if anyone could Point me in the right direction, it'd be great!

thanks.

Comment: this is how the browser renders the element... the rounded edges are part of the element - so I don't think that this can be done (unless you use some html 5 canvas element on top or something - but this is very messy...

Answer (score 3):

You can use SVG for that. SVG is cross browser capable.

```
<svg>
    <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="24"/>
</svg>

circle:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    background: yellow;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Jpnre/
MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Getting_Started/SVG_graphics

Comment: Cross browser compatible except in-not-that-much-older versions of IE (I'm talking version 8 here), which has no SVG support whatsoever.